# When this is executed: `"(exec -l -a specialname /bin/bash -c 'echo $0' ) 2> error"`, why it outputs `[7^[[r^[[999;999H^[[6n` to stderr

Tags: bash, testing, escaping, character

when I do the bash test:

```
(exec -l -a specialname /bin/bash -c 'echo $0' ) 2> error
```

the run-builtins fails, after some search, I found that it outputs

```
^[7^[[r^[[999;999H^[[6n
```

to the stderr, so I redirect it to a file error.
If I cat it, it output a blank line.
I opened it using vim with which I found the:

```
^[7^[[r^[[999;999H^[[6n
```

why?

Comment: This looks like the escape sequence to set the terminal window size.  I can't quite parse what you are asking besides that.  It looks like you have a couple of other questions, though. Could you re-phrase to be clearer?

Comment: Thanks, I want to ask who output the escape sequence, the exec command or the terminal?

Comment: Does the "exec -l" would output a blank line to the stderr?

Comment: It's probably the prompt, which goes to stderr.  I can't reproduce your error, but try unsetting the prompt `-c 'PS1=;echo $0'`.

Comment: Yes, I found the PS1 in the subshell is a blank line, but when I unsetting the prompt -c 'PS1=;echo $0;echo ${PS1}', the unsetting didn't not work, the PS1 is also blank line.

Comment: I test it this way: (exec -l -a specialname /bin/bash -c 'export PS1="test"; echo ${PS1}') 2> err.log, the err.log is also ^[7^[[r^[[999;999H^[[6n, oh, I was crazy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

run the command:

```
(exec -l -a specialname /bin/bash -c 'export PS1='test';echo ${PS1}') 2> err.log
```

[image]

```
vi err.log
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I found that bash read the /etc/profile file, and in this file, has the following:

`if [ -x /usr/bin/resize ];then
  /usr/bin/resize >/dev/null
fi`

so the bash execute the resize program, this program is produced by busybox in my system, the busybox source code console-tools/resize.c has:

```
fprintf(stderr, ESC"7" ESC"[r" ESC"[999;999H" ESC"[6n")
```

so it output that to stderr.